# How will I prove that the simultaneous limits for the following exist?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y) = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\end{align}

Actually I only know how to prove that simultaneous limits does not exist . So please give me a detailed explanation how I can prove that the simultaneous or double limit exist .

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Note that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. So $$0\le\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\le|y|.$$